# I have an array of colors and I want to assign the colors with the labels in the for loop in C#. How can I do so?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

```
Color[] brickcolor = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Orange, Color.Pink, Color.Purple, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Honeydew, Color.Lavender };

            for (int c = 0; c <= 10; c++)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r <= 8; r++)
                {
                    Label bricks = new Label();
                    bricks.Location = new Point(x, y);
                    bricks = brickcolor;
                    bricks.Width = 90;
                    bricks.Height = 25;
                    pnlGame.Controls.Add(bricks);
                    y += 30;
                 }
              }
```

Comment: Is this C# winforms??

Comment: @apomene 
Yes i am using windows forms c#

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
{
 Label bricks = new Label();
 bricks.Location = new Point(x, y);
 bricks.BackColor = brickcolor[r]; //or bricks.ForeColor
 bricks.Width = 90;
 bricks.Height = 25;
 pnlGame.Controls.Add(bricks);
 y += 30;
}
```